# How to send logs from Vercel serverless functions (Next.js) to Google cloud Logs

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, next.js, stackdriver, vercel

From the [Google cloud logging node sdk docs](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-logging#writing-to-stdout):

> Serverless applications like Cloud Functions, Cloud Run, and App Engine are highly recommended to use the LogSync class as async logs may be dropped due to lack of CPU.

This is my implementation of google cloud logging with `LogSync` class

```js
import { Logging } from "@google-cloud/logging";
const creds = {
  private_key:
    '---',
  client_email: "---",
};

const logging = new Logging({
  projectId,
  credentials: creds,
});

const log = logging.logSync(logName);

  const metadata = {
    resource: { type: "global" },
    severity,
    textPayload,
    jsonPayload,
  };

  const CombinedEntry = log.entry(metadata);


  log.alert(CombinedEntry);
```

I'm using this in next.js framework and deploying on Vercel (as [serverless functions](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/serverless-functions))

These logs are visible in the console (stdout) and Vercel functions dashboard but aren't visible on Google cloud logging.

Do I need to configure `LogSync` to mention that it should also send logs to google cloud logging? It's not mentioned in the docs.
We also tried `logging.log` instead of `logging.LogSync` but still logs aren't visible on cloud but just on stdout.

Comment: Did you already configure the drain logs in Vercel? If yes, which type of log drain did you choose?

Comment: I didn't setup any log drain. I couldn't find any resource on how to set it up for google cloud logging.

Comment: I found this guide to create a custom log drain in Vercel [1], it seems that Vercel only allows you to configure the integrations in their marketplace but does not provide support or guides to manually configure another service that does not have an integration created. [1]https://github.com/valeriangalliat/vercel-custom-log-drain

Comment: that guide is still half-picture.. not sure how to setup a sink for google cloud logging that is compatible with vercel integration

Comment: In this post, they  talk about creating a custom log drain (Providing your own URL to handle the logs) to connect to a VM in GCP. Is this tutorial useful to you? https://www.codejam.info/2021/09/vercel-custom-log-drain.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution for getting Vercel logs into Cloud Logging https://github.com/kym6464/vercel-google-cloud-logging. It requires some manual configuration but it gets the job done.